# Cell Style from within view model MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have created a column within the VM of a WPF application like so:

```
GridColumn ShiftProfit = new GridColumn(); 
ShiftProfit.Name = "ShiftProfit"; 
ShiftProfit.Header = "Shift Profit"; 
ShiftProfit.Width = 95; 
ShiftProfit.FieldName = "ShiftProfit"; 
ShiftProfit.ReadOnly = true;
```

As you can see i have already set some properties of the GridColumn but i can't find out how to set it so that it displays a % after the value.

Comment: Where do you store data ? ObservableCollection? Datagrid?

Comment: Is it *DevExpress* `GridColumn` class?

Comment: That's not mvvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set the `StringFormat` of the `Binding`:

```
GridColumn ShiftProfit = new GridColumn();
ShiftProfit.Name = "ShiftProfit";
ShiftProfit.Header = "Shift Profit";
ShiftProfit.Width = 95;
ShiftProfit.Binding = new Binding("ShiftProfit") { StringFormat = "P2" };
ShiftProfit.ReadOnly = true;
```